# ECHO COLUMN VALUE FROM 3RD UP TO THE LAST PHP

Tags: php

i want to echo 3rd column's value up to the last column

i know i can do this by echo `$result[3]`; echo `$result[4]`; echo `$result[5]`; and so on up to the last but is there any way to do it this way echo `$result[3]` UNTIL `$result[last];` ?
please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: a simple for loop with the index starting at 3 should help...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is something you should have learned the first day you started using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return numeric indices from DB query and simple `for` loop. Notice the `MYSQL_NUM` flag added:

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    for ($index = 3; $index < count($result); $index++) {
       echo $result[$index];
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
An alternative. Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` and access your data using column names instead of numeric indices. This improves readablity of code as well.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: tnx it has displayed the value but there's an error saying undefined offset 9 up to 17? what do you think is the problem tnx so much

Comment: You should post your code and what you have in `$result` variable.

Comment: $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username='$username'"); while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))

Comment: undefined offset 9 up to 17 saying that you have attempted to reference a value of an array that does not exist...try my answer

Comment: @christmarq38 Updated answer with an alternative way to your problem.

Comment: it will not work that way sir i know that that THAT really works but that wont work with what im doing i reall need it that way pls help me sir i will post the output w/c you guys told me and i will tell also what output i want thank you verry much sir for your help

Comment: @christmarq38 You need to use `MYSQL_NUM` flag then. Updated answer.

Comment: sir please try to find whats going wrong with your first code that's what im looking for

Comment: thank you very very much sir Im0rtality you're the best sir the 1st one worked well